# Bind two observables in knockout.js

Tags: binding, knockout.js, observable, subscribe

I have two simple observables, for example,

```
val1 = ko.observable("input1");
val2 = ko.observable("input2");
```

and I want them to act like one, so when one of them changes, the other changes as well.

I know that in common case it's better to use only one observable and bind it to several dom elements. But in my case theese observables live in different templates and objects, so they can't be one variable.

Currently I subscribe one observable to another and vice versa:

```
val1.subscribe(function(v) {
    val2(v);
});
val2.subscribe(function(v) {
    val1(v);
});
```

However when you change the value of one observable, it updates the second, but that causes a ripple effect and updates the first one again, ad infinitum.

How can I set up a two-way binding between two separate observables which sets the value of one when you modify the other without causing an infinite loop?

Comment: Are you sure using one property isn't possible? Can you provide a little more detail about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Manual subscriptions would be a fine way to go.  If you are looking for a solution that helps communicate between decoupled view models, then you might consider something like: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox.  It just depends on your scenario.  The other thing that you could do is just have a reference to the same observable in both view models.  They can have different names, etc., but they would point to the same observable.

Comment: This question is pretty decent. I don't understand why those guys closed it.

Comment: This could be a useful helper:

`ko.subscribable['fn'].syncWith = function (targetObservable, callbackTarget, event) {
 var sourceObservable = this;
 sourceObservable.subscribe(function (v) {
  targetObservable(v);
 }, callbackTarget, event);
 targetObservable.subscribe(function (v) {
  sourceObservable(v);
 }, callbackTarget, event);
 return sourceObservable;
    }`
Use it: `val1.syncWith(val2)`

Comment: I created an extender which was useful for me in a similar situation:

Comment: `ko.extenders.doubleBind = function (target, option) {
    var aInput, bInput;
    target.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        if (!bInput) {
            aInput = true;
            option(newValue);
            aInput = false;
        }
    });
    option.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        if (!aInput) {
            bInput = true;
            target(newValue);
            bInput = false;
        }
    });
    return target;
};`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
vm1 = {
    val1: ko.observable('input1'),
    otherProperty: ko.observable('more')
}

vm2 = {
    val2: vm.val1,
    otherProperty: ko.observable('data')
}
```

Both `vm1.val1` and `vm2.val2` resolve to the same observable and therefore the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Sethi's answer will work, but this might be better served with [computed observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

Example: http://jsbin.com/exipuq/1/edit

```
var viewModelA = function(){
  this.myVal = ko.observable();
};

var viewModelB = function(otherViewModel){
  this.compVal = ko.computed(function(){
    return otherViewModel.myVal(); 
  });
};

// create a new viewmodel like normal
var vma = new viewModelA();

// pass the instantiated view model 
// into the new one you're creating    
var vmb = new viewModelB(vma);
```